# How to see ESlint warnings on local machine when using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, github-actions

I have a project based on create-react-app and when I run it locally I get zero ESlint warnings or errors, that's when running npm start and npm build.

When I try to publish to Azure using GitHub Actions I get loads of errors on build, errors such as "no-unused-vars", "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" etc.

I can see this is because GitHub Actions is turning warnings into errors because of the following...

> Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
>
> Most CI servers set it automatically.

I'd like to be able to fix all of these errors but when I build locally it doesn't show warnings. I've tried various things like adding a .env file with CI = true, trying to set the ESlint config etc but nothing I do will make it fail when I run or build the site locally.

Comment: I doubt ESLint loads dotenv, so `.env` won't help, and it's unclear what else you've tried. Why not just add a script to your package file that runs the linter?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe I'm not sure how to write my own script to run it. My understanding was that create-react-app runs Eslint under the hood but doesn't allow you to configure it unless you eject?

Comment: Do you know how to add a scripts entry to the package file? How to run ESLint generally? As to configuring it, see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a read and try to set something up.